# Ping time between two docker containers doesn't changed

Tags: docker, containers, ping, hping

I want to measure the ping time between two docker containers c1(6bf5cc8ba2f9) and c2(b283c3556553) when latency is increased. To emulate latency, I used hping3 tool which generates large number of ICMP echo requests with a very short interval between them:

```
home@vm:~$ docker exec -it 6bf5cc8ba2f9 /bin/bash 
root@c1:/# hping3 --icmp --count 10000 --interval u1000 b283c3556553
```

[image]

Then from the same container (c1) I measured the ping time to c2:

```
home@vm:~$ docker exec -it 6bf5cc8ba2f9 /bin/bash 
root@c1:/# ping b283c3556553
```

What I expected was to see increasing in rtt compared to before traffic generating but the time was not increased.

[image]

Do you know where is the issue? and is there any solution that we can increase the latency between two docker container by generating traffic?